# Unable to restart puppetserver service

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I'm setting up puppetserver on a machine running debian. When I restart the server using the following command

`sudo service puppetserver restart`
I'm getting the following error

```
Job for puppetserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status puppetserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I checked for the log and it shows as follows.I've followed the puppet docs https://puppet.com/docs/puppetserver/5.3/install_from_packages.html for installation.

```
admin@puppet:~$ sudo journalctl -xe
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.webserver.jetty9_core$eval35478$start_webserver_BANG___35483$fn__35484.invoke(jetty9_core.clj:
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.webserver.jetty9_core$eval35478$start_webserver_BANG___35483.invoke(jetty9_core.clj:687)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.webserver.jetty9_core$start_server_single_default.invokeStatic(jetty9_core.clj:939)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.webserver.jetty9_core$start_server_single_default.invoke(jetty9_core.clj:936)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.webserver.jetty9_core$eval35919$start_BANG___35924$fn__35925.invoke(jetty9_core.clj:1036)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.webserver.jetty9_core$eval35919$start_BANG___35924.invoke(jetty9_core.clj:1031)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.webserver.jetty9_service$reify__36326$service_fnk__5266__auto___positional$reify__36333.start(
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$eval5068$fn__5082$G__5058__5085.invoke(services.clj:9)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$eval5068$fn__5082$G__5057__5089.invoke(services.clj:9)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13835$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___13842$fn__13843.invoke(internal.clj:198)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13835$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___13842.invoke(internal.clj:181)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13864$run_lifecycle_fns__13869$fn__13870.invoke(internal.clj:231)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13864$run_lifecycle_fns__13869.invoke(internal.clj:208)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval14346$build_app_STAR___14355$fn$reify__14365.start(internal.clj:586)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval14392$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___14399$fn__14400$fn__14402.invoke(internal.clj:612
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval14392$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___14399$fn__14400.invoke(internal.clj:610)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval14392$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___14399.invoke(internal.clj:604)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at clojure.core$partial$fn__4761.invoke(core.clj:2521)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13905$initialize_lifecycle_worker__13916$fn__13917$fn__14013$state_machine__11875__auto___
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13905$initialize_lifecycle_worker__13916$fn__13917$fn__14013$state_machine__11875__auto___
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:1012)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:1011)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:1016)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:1014)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at clojure.core.async$ioc_alts_BANG_$fn__12043.invoke(async.clj:383)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at clojure.core.async$do_alts$fn__11989$fn__11992.invoke(async.clj:252)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__6799$fn__6800.invoke(channels.clj:95)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu puppetserver[2708]: Background process 2716 exited before start had completed
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu systemd[1]: Failed to start puppetserver Service.
-- Subject: Unit puppetserver.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit puppetserver.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu sudo[2698]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu systemd[1]: Stopped puppetserver Service.
-- Subject: Unit puppetserver.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit puppetserver.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 10 11:02:33 puppet.server.uservi.edu systemd[1]: Starting puppetserver Service...
-- Subject: Unit puppetserver.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit puppetserver.service has begun starting up.
Apr 10 11:02:47 puppet.server.uservi.edu sudo[2927]:    admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Apr 10 11:02:47 puppet.server.uservi.edu sudo[2927]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by admin(uid=0)
```

Comment: need to see the puppetserver.log files to see the beginning of the stack strace.  you can also try starting puppet server directly instead of via systemd

Comment: @balder what do u mean by start directly? Also I couldn't find location of puppetserver.log can u let me know where can I find it?

Comment: location of the logs are in /var/log/puppetlabs/.  By start directly i mean manually run the command that is specified in your systemd startup scrtip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the `/etc/hosts` file to add an alias called `puppet` to my machines fqdn.